# out-of-the-box sensor nodes ready for deployment

Tags: hardware, sensors, deployment

I am on the lookout for sensor-nodes that do not require any DIY or sensor interfacing.

### Purpose

This is because, at times one might just want to setup an IoT Network without having to program or interface certain sensors just to build a proof of concept

### Current Finding

```
Product            |          Positives              | Drawbacks


TI Sensortags     |  * Easy to configure via Apps   |   * Changing Cloud 
                                                           Endpoint not 
                     * Various sensors on-board     |     possible via App
                                                         * By Default send
                     *WLAN/BLE/DualBand                    information
                                                           to IBM Cloud
                                                         * TI is notorious 
                                                           for not being
                                                           developer 
                                                           friendly with
                                                           software
                                                          * Extremely 
                                                            complicated
                                                            Setup with
                                                            Code Composer 
                                                            Studio
```

I wish to create a *inventory* summary for IoT Development (on the forum too via this thread) which have the following features:

1. `Out-of-the-box` or `Off-the-shelf` Products
2. Few Configuration Efforts for sensor nodes (via Apps or simple utilities)
3. deployment ready
4. No sensor shields or mounting sensor boards + programming
5. Avoid use of Gateways (WLAN Technology)

   a. If Gateway exist it should be `out-of-the-box`.

Are there some other nodes that are available with the following features?

Comment: Might this be more on-topic on https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ? Or on Meta here? I suspect it won't be on-topic, unless in meta or chat, but I would love to see this answered

Comment: I was thinking about shifting this to meta but was not sure about it. Can someone port this to meta?

Comment: If they don't just copy, paste, delete ;-) A gerta question! I would personally like to know 1) what the devices are actually sensing and 2) what their interface is, both "physical", in the sense of RS232, WiFi, etc and protocol, such as Modbus, CANbus, proprietary. This could become canonical

Comment: I agree. I do have a clear motive here i.e. mature products in IoT ready for deployments and tests. Your points would make it more concrete.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, not a great question for meta, since that is designed for discussion of the *Stack exchange network* etc.  Hardware recs could be an option, though.